# How do I recover WordPress page content from MySQL database?

Tags: wordpress, mysql, database, backups, phpmyadmin

I have a WordPress site and the database has become corrupted (long story), and it's not backed up. My plan is to create a new WordPress site from scratch and copy all the theme files, images, etc...over from the old site.

What I need to know is how to access the content from my posts and pages. I'm a novice when it comes to databases. I just want to see the post/page content as plain text so I can copy & paste it to the new site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is truely 'corrupted' as you stated, you are unlikely to be able to retrieve your post/page content. In either case, it is located inside your MySQL database inside the `wp_posts` table and more specifically the `post_content` column.